# Получение сивола с строки в PHP

Tags: php

Написал функцию которая сравнивает строки по символам, и возращает количество вхождений.
Но в результате, $one и $two - выдают что попало:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> ```
> function sumStr($stra, $strb) {
>   $sum = 0;
>   
>   for($i = 0; $i < strlen($stra); $i++) {
>     
>     if(strlen($strb) <= $i) break;
>
>     $one = $stra[$i];
>     $two = $strb[$i];
>
>     if($one == $two) { $sum++; echo "$one ^ $two : $sum" . PHP_EOL; }
> }
>
> return $sum; }
> ```

Comment: для однобайтовых строк данный код работал бы.

Comment: @teran, не могу найти информации об этом. Как ее сделать однобайтовой, кодировка?

Comment: `mb_substr` используйте для получения символа в позиции и весь вопрос.